# select best comb among all combination data.table r

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose there are a few firm combination result in certain best value, how to efficiently select unique best combination that every firm appear only once the data.table way?

The sample data:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
allcombs <- data.table(val=sample(1:20,15), t(combn(LETTERS[1:6], 2)))
setnames(allcombs, paste0("V",1:2), paste0("firm",1:2))
copy_sets = copy(allcombs)

allcombs
    val firm1 firm2
 1:  16     A     B
 2:   5     A     C
 3:  12     A     D
 4:  15     A     E
 5:   9     A     F
 6:  19     B     C
 7:   6     B     D
 8:   4     B     E
 9:   2     B     F
10:   7     C     D
11:  14     C     E
12:  10     C     F
13:  11     D     E
14:  20     D     F
15:  13     E     F
```

I can do this with a loop:

```
all_elements = unique(c(allcombs$firm1, allcombs$firm2))
selected_pairs = data.table()
while (length(all_elements) > 0){
  selected_pairs <- rbind(selected_pairs, allcombs[allcombs[firm1 == all_elements[1] | firm2 == all_elements[1], .I[which.max(val)]]])
  all_elements <- setdiff(all_elements, unlist(allcombs[allcombs[firm1 == all_elements[1] | firm2 == all_elements[1], .I[which.max(val)]],.(firm1,firm2)]))
  allcombs <- allcombs[firm1 %in% all_elements & firm2 %in% all_elements]
}
```

Here is what I wanted:

```
selected_pairs
   val firm1 firm2
1:  16     A     B
2:  14     C     E
3:  20     D     F
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is exacltly the optimization criteria? why not select `B,C,19`, `D,F,20`, `A,E,15` which results in a higher cumulated value?

Comment: The criteria is which unique Firm combination that  every firm only appear only once and have the Max or Min value. Such as combination of A, A-B have value 16, A-C have value 5,  A-D 12, A-E  15 and  A-F 9, which A-B is the Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to select the unique best combinations where every firm appears only once.

The code below picks the combination with the highest `val`, marks all other rows which contain `firm1` or `firm2` as *done* and iteratively continues with the remaining rows until all rows are *done*. Bookeeping is done by updating the  `rank` column *by reference*, i.e., without copying.

```
d <- copy(allcombs)
setorder(d, -val)
d[, rank := NA_integer_]
r = 0L
remain <- d[, .I]
while (length(remain) > 0) {
  r <- r + 1L
  idx <- remain[d[remain, which.max(val)]]
  d[idx, rank := r]
  lut <- d[idx, .(firm = c(firm1, firm2), rank = NA_integer_)]
  d[lut, on = c("firm1==firm", "rank"), rank := 0]
  d[lut, on = c("firm2==firm", "rank"), rank := 0]
  remain <- d[, .I[is.na(rank)]]
}
d[rank > 0]
```

> ```
>      val  firm1  firm2  rank
>    <int> <char> <char> <int>
> 1:    20      D      F     1
> 2:    19      B      C     2
> 3:    15      A      E     3
> ```

Note that the result here differs from OP's result as the data.table is ordered by decreasing `val` while OP's code iterates over the rows in order in which the company names appear in `firm1` and `firm2`.

I find this arbitrary and not conclusive. OP's approach will select only suboptima within the combinations of the current `firm1` instance but not the overall optimum of *all* the remaining rows.

---

#### Edit 2

Here is a simplified version of above code which uses an additional *row id* `rn` column instead of the `remain` vector:

```
d <- copy(allcombs)
d[, rank := NA_integer_] # append bookkeeping column
d[, rn := .I] # append row id
r = 0L
while (any(is.na(d$rank))) {
  r <- r + 1L
  idx <- d[is.na(rank), rn[which.max(val)]]
  d[idx, rank := r]
  lut <- d[idx, .(firm = c(firm1, firm2), rank = NA_integer_)]
  d[lut, on = c("firm1==firm", "rank"), rank := 0L]
  d[lut, on = c("firm2==firm", "rank"), rank := 0L]
}
d[rank > 0]
```

---

#### Edit 1

Out of curiosity I have tried to reproduce OP's expected result. So, here is a variant of the code above which loops over the unique company names:

```
d <- copy(allcombs)
firms <- d[, unique(c(firm1, firm2))]
# firms <- rev(d[, unique(c(firm1, firm2))])
d[, rank := NA_integer_]
d[, rn := .I] # append row id
r = 0L
for (f in firms) {
  r <- r + 1L
  idx <- d[is.na(rank) & (firm1 == f | firm2 == f), rn[which.max(val)]]
  d[idx, rank := r]
  lut <- d[idx, .(firm = c(firm1, firm2), rank = NA_integer_)]
  d[lut, on = c("firm1==firm", "rank"), rank := 0L]
  d[lut, on = c("firm2==firm", "rank"), rank := 0L]
  if (!any(is.na(d$rank))) break
}
d[rank > 0]

     val  firm1  firm2  rank    rn
1:    16      A      B     1     1
2:    14      C      E     3    11
3:    20      D      F     4    14
```

As mentioned above, the result may depend on the order of appearance of company names in `firm1` and `firm2`.

This can be demonstrated by reversing the order of company names by

```
firms <- rev(d[, unique(c(firm1, firm2))])
```

Now, the code returns

```
     val  firm1  firm2  rank    rn
1:    15      A      E     2     4
2:    19      B      C     4     6
3:    20      D      F     1    14
```

The bookkeeping columns have not been removed for demonstration.

Comment: Great! I do ignore the optimality. Thank you very much!